# problem in display image with loadDataWithBaseURL() in Android

Tags: android, webview

In my Application, I display data in webview but it can't display the images in the webview.

I used loadDatawithBaseURL() method.

This is my code..

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///059600656X/", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", "about:blank");

// here data is a string object which contain html parsing data.

I think it cant find the images in given directory.

Can Anybody help me?

Comment: no. there is no any comment in the logcat.

Comment: Please search for similar questions before posting a new one... Just yesterday someone asked about this and found a way to solve his problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630829/android-display-res-viewable-in-webview. If I could, I'd vote to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use simple `file:///` URLs with `loadDataWithBaseURL()`, and `"about:blank"` probably is not a valid base URL.

Answer (score 0):

To make the loadDataWithBaseURL work you need to make sure of two things:

All image src include "file:///android_asset/imagename"

and the images are in the asset folder!!

So contrary to answer1, it is as simple as that!

Munir Syed

Answer (score 0):

When you use LoadDataWithBaseURL you must specify the image resource as ur baseurl and data must be ur array or image renderer.

example

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", srray[position], "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

this should help me out