# Load images in html

Tags: android, webview

I have a html file saved in memory and this file have some images (tag ). I can't load these images because they are in the assets folder and I don't know the absolute path. What is the absolute path to assets folder? I think that with the absolute path of the images I could to load these images in my html file into my webview.

Comment: possible duplicate of [@Android display /res/viewable in WebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630829/android-display-res-viewable-in-webview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better try inline images. 
http://www.google.de/search?q=inline+images&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox

Comment: I can't to do it. I need to reference these images by its absolute path. That's why, I need the absolute path of the assets folder