# android webview marquee string can't replace some string with image

Tags: android

i want to reaplace + with up.png imagae bt image is not generated on webview..... so give me help.

thanks in advance.

```
    str = str.replaceAll("\\+","<img src=drawable/up.png/ >");
    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
     String summary = "<html><body><marquee>"+str+"</marquee></body></html>";
     web.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Please, try to explain better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your img src location is incorrect.  Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630829/android-display-res-viewable-in-webview). I think the src should be `'file:///android_res/drawable/up.png'`.

Comment: i tried <img src='res/drawable/up.png' /> but it is not worked.... plz tell me some other possibility