# Webview: Cannot display local image on phone but displays on emulator

Tags: android

I have went through all the posts on displaying local images on android phone. I can see the local image on emulator but on phone - "Webpage not available". However I can load other webpages on phone with webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");

I have set internet permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

The image is in raw folder and using display.html file to read it

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/display.html");
```

// display.html in raw folder

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="file:///android_res/raw/image.jpg" width="50px" alt="Hello">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you by any chance running the code on a phone with API Level < 8 (Android 2.1 and lower) and testing it on an emulator running a more recent version?

`file:///android_res/...` [only works for 2.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630829/android-display-res-viewable-in-webview).

Alternatively you can try putting the image in the assets folder and reference it by `file:///android_asset/...`, which apparently is also supported on devices running older versions. Unfortunately you will lose the ability to automatically load up resources appropriate to the device's screen size and density.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. My emulator is 2.3.1 and phone has 2.1 version. Using assets folder, I can display the image in 2.1 as well